# Find the parameter region where function returns negative value

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, functions

I have a function $f(m,n)$ where m and n are positive integers. Suppose $f(m,n)$ is like a black box, I can get values of it when I enter values of m and n.  I want to scan over a region for example $4<m<100, 4<n<1000$ to find where $f(m,n)<0$. Then make a plot of the region where it satisfies the requirement.

For the plot part, I think I can directly use the Listplot if I can successfully generate a parameter list for m and n where $f(m,n)<0$. For the first part, I could use the command For to generate the list satisfying the requirement. I guess this is not the most ideal command I want to use in Mathematica.

Comment: So if you have something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3spv.png) with 9025 randomly positive and negative points would you be interested in defining positive/negative parametric regions, shown in two colors?

Answer (score 2):

Does RegionPlot work for what you need? It takes an inequality and a range as input and shows the regions in which that function is true. Below, I have included code that gives an example.

`RegionPlot[Sin[x]^y - 10 < 0, {x, 0, 1000}, {y, 0, 1000}]` displays [image: plot goes here]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I should be more precise with my question. My function is sort of like a black box. When I enter values of m and n, it returns me some value.

Comment: It's not perfect, but you could do something like this: f[x_, y_] := RandomReal[{0, x}] - RandomReal[{0, y}]*2

ListPlot@
 Table[If[f[x, y] < 0, {x, y}, Nothing], {x, 0, 10, .1}, {y, 0, 
   10, .1}]

Comment: @Vayne You only have to substitude `Sin[x]^y - 10 `  by your mystical `f[x,y] ` in @Romanp 's  nice answer and it should work!

Comment: That won't work if there's random number generation or something involved in f, but otherwise, should be fine.

Comment: @Romanp  Clearly , but OP speaks of a function which returns a hopefully unique value!